# Let $J$ be a $k \times k$ jordan block, prove that any matrix which commutes with $J$ is a polynomial in $J$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $J$ be a $k \times k$ jordan block, prove that any matrix which commutes with $J$ is a polynomial in $J$.

I appreciate your hints, Thanks

Comment: quite a distance to the full result, which is more than you asked. Do the 2 by 2 and 3 by 3 cases by hand, you will learn something. Actually, the 1 by 1 case as well...

Comment: Thanks, I can prove (doing case by case) that All powers of $J$ commute with $J$, but that does not prove anything... should I assume that some $2 \times 2$ matrix which is not a polynomial in $J$ does not commute with $J$ ?

Comment: You will do what you want, I suppose. I suggest you write out a 2 by 2 Jordan block, call the eigenvalue e or something, write a general 2 by 2 matrix with entries a,b,c,d, multiply in both orders and see what conditions make them commute. Because of Cayley-Hamilton, for 2 by 2 any polynomial need only be linear, $M = A I + B J$

Comment: Let's see, for 3 by 3 9 entries, maybe a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i, one eigenvalue, maybe w, and the polynomials to be considered need only be quadratic, $AI + B J + C J^2.$ Anyway, I think you are a bit over your head, and hands-on manipulation of concrete examples, small enough to be done by a human being, is going to teach you more than me parroting some proof. The very best outcome is if the concrete examples lead you to your own proof.

Comment: Another easy way to prove the result (well depending on how much theory you know) is the fact that each Jordan block necessarily has a cyclic vector since the minimal and characteristic polynomials for a Jordan block are equal. This in turn implies (via the cyclic vector theorem) that each matrix which commutes with the $J$ is a polynomial in $J$.

Comment: @EuYu Thanks for this insightful comment

Answer (score 11):

One direction of the equivalence is easy. For any polynomial $p$ and any square matrix $A$, $p(A)A=Ap(A)$.

For the other direction, we can assume that the $k\times k$ Jordan block $J_k$ has zeros on the diagonal. Indeed, any other Jordan block can be written in the form $\beta I + J_k$ and it is easy to see that $A$ commutes with $\beta I+J_k$ if and only if it commutes with $J_k$.

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be a $k\times k$ matrix and assume that $AJ_k-J_kA=0$. 
We first show that the this implies that $A$ is an upper triangular (UT) and Toeplitz (T) matrix
and proceed by induction on $k$. So assume that if a $(k-1)\times (k-1)$ matrix commutes with a $(k-1)\times (k-1)$ Jordan block, it is UT&T.
Let's write $J_k$ and $A$ in the partitioned form
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}^*&\alpha_{22}\end{bmatrix},
\quad
J_k=\begin{bmatrix}J_{k-1}&e_{k-1}\\0&0\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $A_{11}$ and $J_{k-1}$ are $(k-1)\times(k-1)$. Let's have a look on the commutator:
$$
\begin{split}
AJ_k-J_kA&=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}^*&\alpha_{22}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}J_{k-1}&e_{k-1}\\0&0\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}J_{k-1}&e_{k-1}\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}^*&\alpha_{22}\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}J_{k-1}-J_{k-1}A_{11}-e_{k-1}a_{21}^*&A_{11}e_{k-1}-J_{k-1}a_{12}-\alpha_{22}e_{k-1}\\a_{21}^*J_{k-1}&a_{21}^*e_{k-1}
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11}J_{k-1}-J_{k-1}A_{11}-e_{k-1}a_{21}^*&(A_{11}-\alpha_{22}I)e_{k-1}-J_{k-1}a_{12}\\a_{21}^*J_{k-1}&a_{21}^*e_{k-1}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{split}
$$

Since $AJ_k-J_kA=0$ by assumption, the last two block rows imply that 
$$
a_{21}^*e_{k-1}=0, \quad a_{21}^*J_{k-1}=0.
$$
The first equation implies that the last entry of $a_{21}=0$ is zero, while the other says that the first $k-2$ entries of $a_{21}$ are zero. Therefore, $a_{21}=0$ and indeed the matrix $A$ is UT (since by the induction assumption, $A_{11}$ is UT).

The first block of $AJ-JA=0$ implies that
$$
A_{11}J_{k-1}-J_{k-1}A_{11}-e_{k-1}a_{21}^*=A_{11}J_{k-1}-J_{k-1}A_{11}=0
$$
because we already showed that $a_{21}=0$ and hence from $A_{11}J_{k-1}-J_{k-1}A_{11}=0$ we have that $A_{11}$ is UT&T (by the induction assumption).

It remains to show that if $A_{11}$ is T then from $(A_{11}-\alpha_{22}I)e_{k-1}-J_{k-1}a_{12}=0$ we have that $A$ is T. We have
$$
(A_{11}-\alpha_{22}I)e_{k-1}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,k-1}\\
\vdots\\
a_{k-2,k-1}\\
a_{k-1,k-1}-\alpha_{22}
\end{bmatrix},
\quad
J_{k-1}a_{12}=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{2,k}\\
\vdots\\
a_{k-1,k}\\
0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Since both vectors are equal, it gives $a_{i,k-1}=a_{i+1,k}$ for $i=1,\ldots,k-2$ and $\alpha_22=a_{k-1,k-1}$. Since $A_{11}$ is UT&T, the diagonal of $A_{11}$ is constant and thus the diagonal of $A$ is constant as well and the last $k-2$ entries of $a_{12}$ are "copies" of the first $k-2$ entries of the last column of $A_{11}$. Therefore, $A$ is T.

Summarizing, $A$ and $J_k$ commute implies that $A$ is a UT&T matrix and consequently it can be written in the form
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & \ldots & a_k \\
    & a_1 & \ldots & a_{k-1} \\
    &     & \ddots & \vdots \\
    &     &        & a_1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
By realizing how the powers of $J_k$ look like, it is easy to see that $A$ can be written as
$$
A=a_1 J_k^0 + a_2 J_k^1 + \ldots + a_k J_k^{k-1} =: p(J_k),
\quad p(t)=a_1+a_2t +\ldots+a_k t^{k-1}.
$$

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2):

2 by 2 only. i really hope you will try the 3 by 3 case by hand, analogous to this:

Aright, eigenvalue $w,$ 
$$ J =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
w & 1 \\
0 & w
\end{array}
\right),
$$
trial
$$ M =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}
\right),
$$

Next
$$ JM =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
wa + c & wb+d \\
wc & wd
\end{array}
\right),
$$
but
$$ MJ =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
wa  & wb+a \\
wc & wd+ c
\end{array}
\right).
$$

We find that $JM = MJ$ precisely when
$$  c = 0 \; \; \mbox{AND} \; \; a=d.   $$ Notice that $w$ does not appear.
Under these conditions,
$$ M =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
a & b \\
0 & a
\end{array}
\right).
$$
That means that $$  M = (a-bw)I + b J,  $$ that is a polynomial in $J.$